# No funciona mi petición GET en mi API REST en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, laravel-10

tardes o noches. Estaba realizando mi proyecto en Laravel, intentando realizar una API usando las migraciones y MySQL como lenguaje para la base de datos que generara dicha migración.
El caso es que cree para una tabla su modelo, migración y controlador, además de fijar la ruta:

Migración llamada "2024_02_15_160735_create_users_table":

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('user_id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('first_surname');
            $table->string('second_surname');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->date('date_of_birth');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->text('email')->unique();
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

El modelo llamado "users.php":

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'first_surname', 'second_surname', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'email', 'phone'];

    public function allowed_users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AllowedUser::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

El controlador llamado "UsersController.php":

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $users = User::all();
        return response()->json($users);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $users = new User;
        $users->name = $request->name;
        $users->first_surname = $request->first_surname;
        $users->second_surname = $request->second_surname;
        $users->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $users->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
        $users->gender = $request->gender;
        $users->email = $request->email;
        $users->phone = $request->phone;
        $users->save();

        $data = [
            'message' => 'User created successfully',
            'user' => $users
        ];

        return response()->json($data);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(User $users)
    {
        //
        return response()->json($users);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(User $users)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $users)
    {
        //
        $users->name = $request->name;
        $users->first_surname = $request->first_surname;
        $users->second_surname = $request->second_surname;
        $users->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $users->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
        $users->gender = $request->gender;
        $users->email = $request->email;
        $users->phone = $request->phone;
        $users->save();

        $data = [
            'message' => 'User updated successfully',
            'user' => $users
        ];

        return response()->json($data);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(User $users)
    {
        //
        $users->delete();
        $data = [
            'message' => 'User deleted successfully',
            'user' => $users
        ];
        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

el archivo "api.php" en donde tengo las rutas:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

//Users
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@index');
Route::post('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@store');
Route::get('/users/{users}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@show');
Route::put('/users/{users}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@update');
Route::delete('/users/{users}', 'App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@destroy');
//Roles
Route::get('/roles', 'App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@index');
//Allowed users
Route::get('/allowedusers', 'App\Http\Controllers\AllowedUsersController@index');
```

El caso es que para la solicitud GET puse esto, aunque aplica igual para POST y no tiene ningún fallo:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users
```

El caso es que al probar hacer otra petición GET pero especificando el ID 2, siendo que ya ingrese los registros manualmente en la base de datos (registros visibles cuando hice el GET para que me de todos los datos):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/2
```

El problema es que cuando lo hice, me soltó este error, ósea la respuesta de hacer la petición:

```
{
  "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 2 limit 1)",
  "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
  "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
  "line": 829,
  "trace": [
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
      "line": 783,
      "function": "runQueryCallback",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php",
      "line": 414,
      "function": "run",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php",
      "line": 2751,
      "function": "select",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php",
      "line": 2740,
      "function": "runSelect",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php",
      "line": 3294,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php",
      "line": 2739,
      "function": "onceWithColumns",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder.php",
      "line": 738,
      "function": "get",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder.php",
      "line": 722,
      "function": "getModels",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Concerns\\BuildsQueries.php",
      "line": 333,
      "function": "get",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php",
      "line": 2046,
      "function": "first",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ImplicitRouteBinding.php",
      "line": 61,
      "function": "resolveRouteBinding",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 959,
      "function": "resolveForRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ImplicitRouteBinding",
      "type": "::"
    },
    {
      "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 961,
      "function": "call_user_func"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
      "line": 41,
      "function": "substituteImplicitBindings",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
      "line": 159,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
      "line": 125,
      "function": "handleRequest",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
      "line": 87,
      "function": "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 119,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 805,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 784,
      "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 748,
      "function": "runRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
      "line": 737,
      "function": "dispatchToRoute",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 200,
      "function": "dispatch",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 144,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
      "line": 31,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
      "line": 21,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php",
      "line": 40,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
      "line": 27,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
      "line": 99,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors.php",
      "line": 62,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php",
      "line": 39,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 183,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
      "line": 119,
      "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 175,
      "function": "then",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
      "line": 144,
      "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\public\\index.php",
      "line": 51,
      "function": "handle",
      "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
      "type": "->"
    },
    {
      "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\taking_the_game\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\resources\\server.php",
      "line": 16,
      "function": "require_once"
    }
  ]
}
```

No sé cómo solucionar este error, espero me puedan ayudar en ello.

Comment: El problema es que en la migración el $table->id() ya crea el campo id, no hay por qué definir un nombre para el campo como tú lo haces “user_id”. Laravel solo está tratando de acceder a dicho campo id de la tabla

Comment: Puedes también optimizar el código en el método store: $user = User::create($request->all());, y en el método update: $user->update($request->all());. Te recomiendo tratar user en singular ya q estás hablando solo de 1, y que hagas las validaciones pertinentes de los datos del modelo antes de almacenarlos

Answer (score 0):

La definición de la tabla debería ser

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->id(); 
   ...
});
```

Es la manera correcta de definir la tabla, con esto al crearse definirá un campo "id" y será primary key. No hace falta definirlo en el modelo.

Sino deberías saltarte los estándares de Laravel y consultar por

```
User::where('user_id', request()->users);
```